# Why does a const object requires a user-provided default constructor?

Tags: c++

Here is a piece of code:

```
class A {
public:
    void f() {}

};

int main()
{
    A a;       // OK
    const A b; // ERROR

    a.f();
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following error: `Default initialisation of an object of const type 'const A' requires a user-provided default constructor`

What is the logic behind this ?

Comment: Deleting my answer, there's already a duplicate

Comment: Interestingly enough, this errors in clang 3.5 but not gcc 4.9.