# Function template specialization and rvalue reference in c++

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

```
    #include <iostream>

    struct Cls{double dval = 0;};

    template<typename T>
    void foo(T&& Obj) {
        //..... use Obj
    } 

    void foo(const Cls& Obj) {
        //..... use Obj.dval
    }

    //void foo(Cls Obj) {
    //    //..... use Obj.dval
    //}

    int main()
    {
        Cls Obj;
        const Cls cv_Obj;

        foo(Obj); //case 1
        foo(Cls{}); //case 2
        foo(cv_Obj); //case 3
        foo(10.10);
    }
```

template specialization for `Cls` fails (`case 1, case 2`) if the function argument is `const ref` but `by val` works for all cases.

Is there any way other than `pass by val`to handle specialization for all `cases` (all value types)?

Comment: Surely the line in your template version should be `std::cout<<Obj.dval;` instead of `std::cout<<Obj;`

Comment: Identifiers starting with underscore are reserved in global namespace.

Comment: `fails` means what? What error do you see?

Comment: I want to use `foo` to print `double, int, etc...` , so for template it must be `std::cout<<Obj;`  
Error:
Except for `foo(cv_Obj);`, `void foo(T&& Obj)` function is invoked.
`error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and '_struct')`

Comment: Please clarify by editing the question.

Comment: Also related for the const-default constructor issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077807/why-does-gcc-allow-a-const-object-without-a-user-declared-default-constructor-bu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this issue using SFINAE, but it would be much easier to get rid of the overload on `_struct` and define an overload for `operator<<`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const _struct& obj)
{
  os << obj.dval;
  return os;
}
```

A possibility for solving with SFINAE would be to check for the validity of outputting `Obj` directly in one overload and check the type against `_struct` in the other:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(T&& Obj) -> decltype(std::cout<<Obj, void()) {
    std::cout<<Obj;
}

template<typename T, 
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<_struct, std::decay_t<T>>::value>* = nullptr>
void foo(T&& Obj) {
    std::cout<<Obj.dval;
}
```

Comment: This is [expression SFINAE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654067/what-is-expression-sfinae). Essentially, if the expression in that decltype is ill-formed, that overload is purged from the candidate set rather than resulting in a hard error.

Answer (score 0):

You need a helper struct:

```
#include <iostream>

struct _struct{double dval = 0;};

template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct bar {
    bar(T&& Obj) {
        std::cout<<Obj;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct bar<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, _struct>::value>::type> {
    bar(T&& Obj) {
        std::cout<<Obj.dval;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void foo(T&& Obj) {
    bar<T>(std::forward<T>(Obj));
}

int main()
{
    _struct Obj;
    const _struct cv_Obj;

    foo(1);
    foo(Obj); //case 1
    foo(_struct{}); //case 2
    foo(cv_Obj); //case 3
    foo("test");
}
```