# Why is gcc and msvc allow const objects without user-provided constructor? Is this a bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

This code:

```
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
};

int main()
{
   const A a;

   return 0;
}
```

can be compiled without errors in Visual C++ (from VS 2015 Update 2) and GCC (5.3.1), but can not be compiled with Clang, it gives this error:

```
test.cpp:8:13: error: default initialization of an object of const type
      'const A' without a user-provided default constructor
           const A a;
                   ^
                    {}
1 error generated.
```

Who is right, clang or gcc and MSVC? **Are other compilers behavior is a bug?**

PS. `const A a{};` is compiled without errors with all three. 
Same if we define empty constructor: `A::A() {}`.

PPS. This is NOT a duplicate. I emphasize the actual question.

**Update** Filed a bug in MSVC: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2538005
S.T.L. said that they are in process of fixing them all to conform clang tests: https://twitter.com/StephanTLavavej/status/715923311796953089

Comment: Why you define the default constructor to default? If you what it default dont declareit, or declare it and define it.

Comment: @AsierSánchezRodríguez Because I can. This is not the question about.

Comment: How about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337951/clang-compile-error-with-default-initialization?lq=1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc is conforming to [DR253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_253.htm); [Why does gcc allow a const object without a user-declared default constructor but not clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077807/why-does-gcc-allow-a-const-object-without-a-user-declared-default-constructor-bu) Note that gcc does not require the presence of the explicitly-defaulted default constructor:

```
struct A {};  // No uninitialized members
int main() {
   const A a; // OK with gcc
}
```

MSVC is non-conformant in that it will allow compilation of the code when `A` has an uninitialized data member, regardless of whether there is an explicitly-defaulted default constructor, but it does at least issue a diagnostic (C4269) so it should be easy to make conformant:

```
struct A { int i; }; // Uninitialized data member
int main() {
   const A a;  // Should be ill-formed; MSVC accepts with diagnostic
}
```

> main.cpp(8): warning C4269: 'a': 'const' automatic data initialized with compiler generated default constructor produces unreliable results

clang has a [patch accepted and ready to land](http://reviews.llvm.org/D5789) (since June 2015) but it appears to have been forgotten.

Comment: Has DR253 made the standard yet? Last I checked (October '15) there was no activity on it, and it was still in "Drafting" status.